# Chrome extension buggy?CaptureVisibleTab don't work with CSS3

Tags: google-chrome, css, google-chrome-extension

When I use captureVisibleTab on page where i put a div with preserve3d in CSS3 there i got blank page :/

How can I fix it?

My simple code to capture the screen browser:

```
 chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {              
      chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, function(img) {
   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "..my url..",
   data: "img=" + img,
   success: function(e){
     alert(e);
   }}); 
      });

});
```

What should I do? How the code must look like to captureVisibleTab works?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. Maybe you should file a bug [here](http://crbug.com/). Note that there are already [some bugs](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list?q=captureVisibleTab) related to this API.